# Использование forceLayout(), requestLayout() и invalidate() в классе View

Tags: android, view

Может мне кто-то разъяснить как работают эти методы? Когда стоит использовать каждый из них? И в чем принципиальная разница каждого из них?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начнем с `inValidate()` ([доки](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate())):

> Вызов `invalidate ()` выполняется, когда вы хотите запланировать
> перерисовку `View`. Это приведет к тому, что `onDraw` будет вызываться
> в конце концов (скоро, но не сразу). Пример того, когда
> пользовательское `View` будет вызывать его, - когда свойство цвета
> текста или фона изменилось.

Дальше `requestLayout()` ([опять доки](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#requestLayout())):

> Если что-то в вашем View изменится, что повлияет на размер, вы должны
> вызвать `requestLayout ()`. Это вызовет onMeasure и onLayout не только
> для этого View , но и до линии родительских View .
>
> Вызов `requestLayout ()` не гарантированно приведет к onDraw, поэтому
> он обычно комбинируется с `invalidate()`.

`ForceLayout()` ([и снова доки](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#forceLayout()))

> `forceLayout ()` работает только с потомком, если он вызывается в
> сочетании с `requestLayout()` у его прямого родителя. Вызов
> `forceLayout ()` сам по себе не будет иметь никакого эффекта, так как
> он не вызывает `requestLayout ()` вверх по дереву представления.

Вот еще схематически:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как android рисуется ([доки](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html)) Подобные вопросы [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13856180/usage-of-forcelayout-requestlayout-and-invalidate), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45383948/how-does-forcelayout-work-in-android/45969662) и [интересный ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62358020/9363441). [Статья](https://medium.com/@britt.barak/measure-layout-draw-483c6a4d2fab) по данной теме.

[Обсуждение](https://gist.github.com/ixiyang/7922825) на гитхабе.

Вероятный [первоисточник](https://android.developreference.com/article/23639942/Usage+of+forceLayout()%2C+requestLayout()+and+invalidate()) текстовой информации (я брал инфу не отсюда :) )

[Документация](https://www.apiref.com/android/android/view/View.html) по api для view. Надеюсь смог вам помочь данным ответом :)

Comment: Спасибочки. Вы мне очень помогли)